# How to branch properly in XSLT?

Tags: xml, algorithm, xslt, branch, xsl-fo

I am trying to branch in XSLT. Here is the run down of what I am trying to do:

I am traversing through an XML file and searching for a value that has matching Section2, Section3, and Section4 (Section 1 and 5 are just used for processing purposes). If all the values match I will print out the corresponding Section5 and then be done with processing.

The issue I am having is if I do not find the three matching sections, for example if I find Section2 and Section3 but not Section4 I need to go back through Section4 and search for a section with value '#'. If I find Section2 and not Section3 I will go back through Section3 search for a '#' then I will go to Secton4 and search for the correct value (If I do not find it I will look for a '#').

I have no idea how to achieve the above functionality. Currently all the code is doing is finding the matching values but it is not handling the pound case described above, any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have included the XSLT below and the XML section below.

```
<xsl:template match="Section1">
    <xsl:param name="sec2"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec3"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section2[./@value=$sec2]">
        <xsl:with-param name="sec3" select="$sec3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section2">
    <xsl:param name="sec3"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section3[./@value=$sec3]">
        <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section3">
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section4[./@value=$sec4]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section4">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section5">
    <!--Value will be printed here-->
</xsl:template>

<Section1>
<Section2 value="AP">
    <Section3 value="JP">
        <Section4 value="true">
            <Section5>Content #1</Section5>
        </Section4>
        <Section4 value="false">
            <Section5>Content #2</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
    <Section3 value="KO">
        <Section4 value="true">
            <Section5>Content #3</Section5>
        </Section4>
        <Section4 value="false">
            <Section5>Content #4</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
    <Section3 value="#">
        <Section4 value="true">
            <Section5>Content #5</Section5>
        </Section4>
        <Section4 value="false">
            <Section5>Content #6</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
</Section2>
<Section2 value="LA">
    <Section3 value="#">
        <Section4 value="true">
            <Section5>Content #7</Section5>
        </Section4>
        <Section4 value="false">
            <Section5>Content #8</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
</Section2>
<Section2 value="NA">
    <Section3 value="#">
        <Section4 value="true">
            <Section5>Content #9</Section5>
        </Section4>
        <Section4 value="false">
            <Section5>Content #10</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
</Section2>
<Section2 value="E">
    <Section3 value="#">
        <Section4 value="#">
            <Section5>Content #11</Section5>
        </Section4>
    </Section3>
</Section2>
```

Comment: Maybe you could add an or to your match, for example `<xsl:template match="Section2 | #">` It is not easy without source XML and expected output. Best regarsd, Peter

Comment: With that or statement wouldn't it choose both the # and the equivalent, meaning if it found the value it would return that and then it would continue looking for the #? Just wondering, and thank you for the help!

Comment: You are right, it would match `Sectin2` and `#`. Would you have a (simplified) example XML - it is always easier to see what you are trying to do. thank you, Peter

Comment: I can write a simplified version but before I do let me explain. Each key of (Section2, Section3, Section4) is unique. I want to search for the matching value and return Section5. If no matching value existed for Section2 we would look for (#, Section3, Section4), if no such value exists for Section4 we would look for (#, Section3, #). Does this make more sense? # basically denotes a default value or a value to go to if no matching section is found.

Comment: I would think you could solve it using `xsl:key` applying a key to Section2, Section3, Section4 and #. Which ever does not exist the respective key would be empty and not be relevant for processing. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question! Basically you need to wrap each section in a variable. Test if a value is returned and if it is print it, otherwise look for a #, below is the code!

```
<xsl:template match="Section1">
    <xsl:param name="sec2"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec3"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section2[./@value=$sec2]">
            <xsl:with-param name="sec3" select="$sec3"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$content = ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section2[./@value='#']">
                <xsl:with-param name="sec3" select="$sec3"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section2">
    <xsl:param name="sec3"/>
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section3[./@value=$sec3]">
           <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$content = ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section3[./@value='#']">
                <xsl:with-param name="sec4" select="$sec4"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section3">
    <xsl:param name="sec4"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section4[./@value=$sec4]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$content = ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section4[./@value='*']"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section4">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section5">
    <!--Value will be printed here-->
</xsl:template>
```

THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!